# Publish .NET application with framework

Tags: .net, libvlc

I made a simple application including VLCPlugin in .NET 2012 including framework 4.

I need to install the application in non-frame work installed machines also. Now when I build the application and try to install on a machine the following error showing.

My question is how to export the entire application including frameworks ? So that clients can install and works the application.

Anyone please help
Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use and installer of some kind. For Visual Studio 2012, you can publish the application using [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and mark .NET 4.0 as a prerequisite. For earlier versions of Visual Studio, you can use a [Setup project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/996a3fxs%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to create an MSI based install; the setup project, like the ClickOnce wizard, should automatically detect the dependency on the .NET 4.0 runtime. You can also use [InstallShield](http://www.installshield.com/) or another commercially available installer creation package. The only other alternative is to tell your users to download either the [standalone](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718) or [web](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851) versions of the .NET installation package from Microsoft.

Comment: Microsoft has a dedicated page for deploying the .NET Framework with your application: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee942965%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For distributing a commercial software, we use WIX - http://wix.sourceforge.net/ . This is free, you can fully customize the installation process and of course detect and install the .Net framework. It has a plugin for Visual Studio and works with VS2012 well.

Comment: Its not a commercial software.. Its only for the internal use only ... any solution ? Also how to deploy for both 32 & 64 bit ? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have a time to build an installer, I recommend it (it's worth the time and money I think even for internal sw) and IMHO the best option is Wix. YMMV, of course, the Visual Studio "setup project" or what's its name is also a decent option. If the application should be installed once per user and not once per machine, you can go for ClickOnce, as Paul Keister recommended (you can not get Windows Logo for it, but for internal sw it does not matter). Or simply instruct your users to install .Net framework, if aplicable, it's the cheapest and fastest way

Comment: ok thanks for your reply .. The problem is internally we got about 450 machines.. Users are not permitted to Internet and admin privilege. Configuration is XP, 64 bit. If this software can be stand alone executed we can save more time of sys admins.. Which will the recommended way ?

Comment: AFAIK you can not embed .Net framework with your software like with Java runtime environment. However you can do that with Mono - just add required libraries with your application and make a batch file/simple exe which only runs "mono yourapp.exe". Even for click once, the user would need to install .Net framework which requires admin priviledge.